# RelativeLayout won't wrap right-aligned TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my messaging app's XML for right-aligned messages (outgoing), I can't get the RelativeLayout to wrap it's content (a TextView that's aligned to the right). I would post a picture, but I'm new here, and need more reputation before that's possible.

The RelativeLayout containing the text (message) has a text bubble sort of background, and I want that to nicely wrap around the text. I got it working easily in my other XML-file, for left-aligned messages (incoming).

To specify, my problem is with the innermost RelativeLayout.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDate"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text=""
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtSender"
                />

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txtSender"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/purple_bubble"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtDate">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                    android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                    android:paddingStart="7dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:text="Hello, how are you?"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap a linear layout inside the relative layout. add layout gravity to the linear layout. this is how i did it. you can use it as your reference,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSms"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/txt_green"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSmsDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#1E2CED"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="10dp" />


   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just try to delete the code `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in textMessage, and I see the text is left-aligned.

I have no idea about why it is, and I don't know what do you want really, just left-aligned? Maybe you can try this or use some other layout to frame your app.